# How to put into list comprehension two for loops?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am looking for an answer how to put into a list comprehension two for loops, where one for loop in embedded into the second one. Is it possible to avoid using for loops also in this example? The goal of this example should be to extract values into one list from the lists which are embedded in another the list.

```
slov = {"abc":[1.0, 2.0], "b": [3.0], "a12": [6.0]}
li = list(slov.keys())
hod = [i for i in li if len(i)==3]
slo = []

for k in hod:
    j = slov[k]
    for l in j:
        slo.append(l)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Always indicate the language / runtime, J. Krc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another couple of nested options.**

First building a new dict with the keys matching the condition:

```
[ item for values in { k: v for k, v in slov.items() if len(k) == 3 }.values() for item in values ]
```

---

Or building a list with the values whose keys are matching the condition:

```
[ item for values in [ v for k, v in slov.items() if len(k) == 3 ] for item in values ]
```

This part `[ v for k, v in slov.items() if len(k) == 3 ]` is returning the result as a nested list `[[1.0, 2.0], [6.0]]`, so it is required to flatten it nesting in a list comprehension.

---

Both returning `#=> [1.0, 2.0, 6.0]`

Answer (score 3):

Using for-loops makes your code more readable and straightforward, however if you insist on a one-liner list comprehension here it is:

```
slov = {"abc":[1.0, 2.0], "b": [3.0], "a12": [6.0]}
slo = [l for k in (i for i in slov.keys() if len(i)==3) for l in slov[k]]

print(slo)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `itertools.chain` to flatten list of values for keys whose length is 3:

```
from itertools import chain

slov = {"abc":[1.0, 2.0], "b": [3.0], "a12": [6.0]}

slo = list(chain.from_iterable(slov[k] for k in slov if len(k) == 3))

print(slo)
# [1.0, 2.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I could see a few answers already given above. Below you will find a slightly modified version of the same.**

```
slov = {"abc":[1.0, 2.0], "b": [3.0], "a12": [6.0]}
print ([j for k, i in slov.items() if len(k) == 3 for j in i]) # Outer Loop (for k, i in slov.items() if len(k) == 3), Inner Loop (for j in i)

# Output - [1.0, 2.0, 6.0]
```

I hope this counts... :)